# looping through columns in a R dataframe

Tags: r

I'm writing a code in R that allow me to draw histograms along with median and the quartiles, but I have problems with cycling in the dataframe columns.

You can find in attach the header of my dataframe and the code.

At the end, histograms are produced but median and quartiles are not linked to the real distributions.

```
  ROI    DOY_119    DOY_127   DOY_143    DOY_151   DOY_175    DOY_191    DOY_215    DOY_239    DOY_263
1   4 -11.592668  -9.457701 -12.57275 -11.073490 -8.999743  -9.132843  -9.995659  -9.511699  -9.393022
2   4 -11.518109 -10.231917 -11.96543 -10.757207 -9.558524  -8.529423  -9.562449  -9.511699  -9.578184
3   4  -9.633711  -9.488475 -12.09012 -10.357404 -8.535619  -8.294449  -9.179331  -7.652297  -6.952941
4   4  -7.752080  -9.578184 -11.30182 -11.073490 -8.992849  -6.197888  -6.556077  -5.883803  -6.324577
5   4 -12.533658  -9.347939 -12.74088 -10.506100 -8.958544 -10.486625 -10.809219 -10.550241  -9.307020
6   4 -13.036436  -8.054857 -13.45823  -9.122186 -7.654827 -10.159230 -10.423927 -11.319436 -10.736576

for (i in 2:ncol(fileIn)){

  myHist <- paste(directory, (i-1), sep="")
  x11(width = 50, height = 50)

  medi <- ddply(fileIn, "ROI", summarise, grp.medi=median (as.numeric(as.matrix(fileIn[i]))))
  q05  <- ddply(fileIn, "ROI", summarise, grp.q05=quantile(as.numeric(as.matrix(fileIn[i]))),0.05)
  q25  <- ddply(fileIn, "ROI", summarise, grp.q25=quantile(as.numeric(as.matrix(fileIn[i]))),0.25)
  q75  <- ddply(fileIn, "ROI", summarise, grp.q75=quantile(as.numeric(as.matrix(fileIn[i]))),0.75)
  q95  <- ddply(fileIn, "ROI", summarise, grp.q95=quantile(as.numeric(as.matrix(fileIn[i]))),0.95)

  plotHist <-
    ggplot(fileIn) +
    aes(x = as.numeric(as.matrix(fileIn[i,]))) +                                              
    # aes(x = DOY_119) +                                              
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, binwidth = 0.5, color="grey", fill= "yellow") +                                       
    geom_density(color = "green", fill= "green", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_vline(data=medi, aes(xintercept=grp.medi), color="red",   size = 0.7) +
    geom_vline(data=q05,  aes(xintercept=grp.q05),  color="black", size = 0.3) +
    geom_vline(data=q25,  aes(xintercept=grp.q25),  color="blue",  size = 0.5) +
    geom_vline(data=q75,  aes(xintercept=grp.q75),  color="blue",  size = 0.5) +
    geom_vline(data=q95,  aes(xintercept=grp.q95),  color="black", size = 0.3) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black")) +         
    facet_wrap( ~ ROI, scales = "free")

  plot(plotHist)

  #------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # salvataggio X11

  dev.copy(jpeg, myHist, width=2000, height=1000, res=100)
  dev.off()
}
```

Comment: When I try to run your code in an empty session, there are a lot of error. For starters, your quantiles don't get defined properly.

Comment: Thank you Heroka. You found the biggest issue, unfortunately I'm a R beginner and I don't know how to solve the problem.

Comment: For example: if you don't use the cycle but you define manually the column, for example [q05 <- ddply(fileIn, "ROI", summarise, grp.q05=quantile(DOY_143,0.05))] seems it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start for you. This is the kind of problem that can be solved in multiple ways, and one is not always better than the other. In your code, you were doing some things quite inefficiently (like calculating the quantiles and creating the `vline`). Generally in ggplot, if you find yourself repeating very similar lines (like 5 calls to vline) there is a better approach. I've replaced with the calculation of one 'vline_data`and fed that to`geom_vline` in combination with some manual scales.

```
#add second ROI for plotting/demonstration purposes
fileIn2 <- fileIn
fileIn2$ROI <- 5

fileIn <- rbind(fileIn,fileIn2)


myplots <- lapply(colnames(fileIn)[-1],function(col_of_interest){
#create summary_data for quantiles
  vline_data <- ddply(fileIn,.(ROI), function(x){
    myprobs=c(0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.95)
    res <- data.frame(prob=as.character(myprobs),value=quantile(x[,col_of_interest],probs=myprobs) )
    res
  })
  #create plot. Note the use of aes_string here.
  plotHist <-
    ggplot(fileIn, aes_string(x=col_of_interest))+
    geom_histogram(alpha = 0.5, binwidth = 0.5, color="grey", fill= "yellow") +                                       
    geom_density(color = "green", fill= "green", alpha = 0.5) +
    geom_vline(data=vline_data, aes(xintercept=value,size=prob,color=prob)) +
    scale_color_manual(values=c("black","blue","red","black","blue"),
                       breaks=as.character(c(0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.95)))+
    scale_size_manual(values=c(0.3,0.5,0.7,0.5,0.3),
                      breaks=as.character(c(0.05,0.25,0.5,0.75,0.95)))+
    facet_wrap( ~ ROI, scales = "free") 
  #optional: use `ggsave` here. 
  #ggsave(file=paste(directory,col_of_interest,".png"),plot=plotHist)
  return(plotHist)
}
)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Heroka, thank you very much. It works fine, but it is still a bit complicate for me. I have to study a lot. Best regards, Giacomo

Comment: You're welcome to ask questions on parts you don't understand. Everybody was a beginner once.